# Two consecutive HTML dropdown menus rendering issue

Tags: html, css, dropdown

I have the following code where I am trying to create two drop down menus; one for the day of the week and other one for the category.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <p>Category of the article: 
    <option value="lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
    <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
    <option value="business">Business</option>
    <option value="social media">Social Media</option>
    <option value="tech">Tech</option>
    <option value="world">World</option></p> <br>
    
    <p>Day of publishing the article: 
    <option value="monday">Monday</option>
    <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
    <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
    <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
    <option value="friday">Friday</option>
    <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
    <option value="sunday">Sunday</option></p> <br>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

But the page looks like the below image. Can someone help me identify why is this  happening?

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mistakes:**

1. You cannot have any block tags or anything inside `<p>`.
2. You missed the `<select>` tags.

**Corrected Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <p>Category of the article:</p>
    <select>
      <option value="lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
      <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
      <option value="business">Business</option>
      <option value="social media">Social Media</option>
      <option value="tech">Tech</option>
      <option value="world">World</option>
    </select>

    <p>Day of publishing the article:</p>
    <select>
      <option value="monday">Monday</option>
      <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
      <option value="friday">Friday</option>
      <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
      <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
    </select>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the `<select>` tag.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
       <title>Titre</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Category of the article: 
    <select>
      <option value="lifestyle">Lifestyle</option>
      <option value="entertainment">Entertainment</option>
      <option value="business">Business</option>
      <option value="social media">Social Media</option>
      <option value="tech">Tech</option>
      <option value="world">World</option>
    </select></p> <br>
    
    <p>Day of publishing the article: 
    <select>
      <option value="monday">Monday</option>
      <option value="tuesday">Tuesday</option>
      <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
      <option value="thursday">Thursday</option>
      <option value="friday">Friday</option>
      <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
      <option value="sunday">Sunday</option>
     </select></p> <br>
    
    </body>
    </html>
```

This code is right in the validator but I'm not sure if you can add `<select>` in `<p>`.

See [HTML select tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

Comment: This doesn't validate if you try it with a validator. Can you check please?

Comment: The only missing thing was the <head> and the <title>, otherwise this is correct.

Comment: No. Check my answer. You cannot have any block elements inside the `<p>` element.

Comment: Sorry. Looks crazy. HTML5 is crazy! `:P`